# Python: Referencing/Assignment with Local/Global Variable within Loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, global, local

I have the following loop structure and also the problem, that it is not possible to increment a variable inside of this code due to `UnboundLocalError`:

```
while True:
    def function_1():
        def function_2():
            x += 1
            print(x)
        function_2()
    function_1()
```

My solution was now this one:

```
x = 0
while True:
    def function_1():
        def function_2():
            global x
            x += 1
            print(x)
        function_2()
    function_1()
```

Is there another solution without `global`?

Answer (score 1):

use a mutable value.

```
x = []
x.append(0)
while True:
    def function_1():
        def function_2():
            x[0]= x[0]+1
            print x[0]
        function_2()
    function_1()
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test which one is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Pass and return x to all the functions.

```
x = 0
while True:
    def function_1(x1):
        def function_2(x2):
            x2 += 1
            print(x2)
            return x2
        return function_2(x1)
    x = function_1(x)
```